# Google Sheets not showing custom function in autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can't get the google sheets autocomplete to show my custom function even when I use Google's version (see below).  I have the jsdoc info correctly formatted, but it still doesn't show up.  I'm sure I'm just overlooking something stupid, but I can't find it.  So what am I missing?

Google's demo code:

```
/**
 * Multiplies the input value by 2.
 *
 * @param {number} input The value to multiply.
 * @customfunction
 */
function double(input) {
  return input * 2;
}
```

BTW, I'm using Chrome to develop my custom functions.  Also, my function works, just no autocomplete.  All the built-in functions autocomplete works.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Brad

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to get the custom function autocomplete working yesterday. It seems to only work with container-bound scripts, so any JSDoc info inside a script being used as a library will not come across. To verify it works, I did the following:

- Create new Google Sheet
- Open Script Editor
- Enter the following in the script:

  ```
  /**
   * Returns amount multiplied by itself.
   *
   * @param {Number} amount The amount to be multiplied by itself.
   * @return {Number} The amount multiplied by itself.
   * @customfunction
   */
  function test(amount) {
    return amount*amount;
  }
  ```
- Then, when entering =test into a cell in the spreadsheet, the information above the function appears in the autocomplete hint, like any other built-in spreadsheet function.